# Normalization 3D Image according to Slices in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, normalization

I have a matrix which is `256X192X80`. I want to normalize all slices (80 represents the slices) without using `for` loop. 
The way I'm doing with `for` is below: (im_dom_raw is our matrix)

```
normalized_raw = zeros(size(im_dom_raw));
for a=1:80
   slice_raw = im_dom_raw(:,:,a);
   slice_raw = slice_raw-min(slice_raw(:));
   slice_raw = slice_raw/(max(slice_raw(:)));
   normalized_raw(:,:,a) = slice_raw; 
end
```

Comment: There's no question here. Please edit to ask a specific question. And it may not be relevant, but if `slice_raw` happens to be all zeros, you'll get `0/0`, i.e., `NaN`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code below implements your normalization approach without using loops. Its based on `bsxfun`.

```
% Shift all values to the positive side
slices_raw = bsxfun(@minus,im_dom_raw,min(min(im_dom_raw)));

% Normalize all values with respect to the slice maximum (With input from @Daniel)
normalized_raw2 = bsxfun(@mrdivide,slices_raw,max(max(slices_raw)));

% A slightly faster approach would be
%normalized_raw2 = bsxfun(@times,slices_raw,max(max(slices_raw)).^-1);
% ... but it will differ with your approach due to numerical approximation

% Comparison to your previous loop based implementation
sum(abs(normalized_raw(:)-normalized_raw2(:)))
```

The last line of code outputs

> ans =
>
> 0

Which (thanks to @Daniel) means that both approaches yield exact same results.

Comment: You get the minor difference because you use different operations, `normalized_raw3 = bsxfun(@mrdivide,slices_raw,max(max(slices_raw)));` and the result is identical, but your version is probably slightly faster.